# My PHP form is clearing the $_GET parameters in my URL

Tags: php, html, forms, url, get

By default, when you visit this page `$_GET['page']` is set to 1. I have a search box that allows users to search the same page using `$_GET['search']` as the search parameter; however it clears the `$_GET['page']` parameter.

Is there a way I can make both parameters stay in the URL when using the search box?

Here's my code:

Search Form:

```
<form action="page.php?page=1" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" />
</form>
```

page.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['search']) && isset($_GET['page'])) {
        // My query goes here
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you using AJAX for search??

Comment: <?php
        if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
     $q=$_GET["search"];}
      else{ $q="1";}

Comment: delete **?page=1** from your form. 

<?php
        if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
     $q=$_GET["search"];}
      else{ $q="1";}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `page` parameter in as a hidden HTML field.

```
<form action="page.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your search form you need a button and you can add an input type hidden and print in his value your `$_GET['page']`, like this :

```
<form action="page.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>" />
    <input name="btn" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```